# Centered or not centered?

Tags: css

I am not a designer but I am trying to learn some basic principles of web-design. A basic question I am wondering about is whether or not to center a page's content on the screen. Maybe you are familiar with [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/). They provide a good number of articles on web-design. What strikes me as odd is their own design. The whole page is to the left of my 24 inch screen (about 11 inch to the right is completely blank). What are the pros and cons of centered vs not centered?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: What are you trying to say, that this question is malplaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An average user of an all-purpose web site [is likely to have](http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/) 1280*1024+ resolution. If you also support 1024*768 (i.e. max 960px width) and put your content to the left side of the screen, users at 1280*1024 would just have to turn their head a little bit but think of a user at 1920*1080, who would need to actually change seating position to clearly read the content, which would be occupying just the left half of the screen.

Apart from those, I don't see any technical advantage or disadvantage of floating to the left.

[image]

Comment: Nice picture! Would there be a problem of just centering instead? I am the user with 1920x1080. This site is centered and works perfectly for me. It looks to be 950px wide but I don't need to turn my head.

Comment: I'm sorry, that wasn't very clear: I meant that you need to turn your head if the web page is left aligned. I mean the full body, not chunks of text, which should be left aligned for easy reading.

Answer (score 1):

People read left justified text faster than centered text.

A List Apart has a content column that's a bit wide for comfortable reading on a large screen.  It's probably the correct size for a smart phone.  People are more comfortable reading columns of text, like a newspaper, than if the text runs across the screen.

If you want to center the entire layout, you can, but it's easier for people to size their browser to fit a left justified layout.  Some people may have 3 or 4 browser windows showing on their wide screens at the same time.  I have two monitors on my work and home computer, and sometimes I'll have 3 browser windows showing at the same time.

Comment: That's a pretty good argument Gilbert: it's easier to size the browser to fit a left-justified layout. Or is it? FF 4 Beta 7 automatically scrolls Stackoverflow to the left when I resize the window to smaller than the width. I would be annoyed if it kept the layout centered. Chrome does the same. Then I don't see the argument any more. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: It's easier for people to size a left-justified layout.  You and I are used to a centered layout shifting as you reduce the size of the browser window.  Others aren't as used to the shifting.  As always, your layout should reflect the needs of your users.